What happened to Albert Annan after divorce from his infamous wife?
Albert Annan (the prototype of Amos Hart, the cheated-on husband of the murderess Roxy in "Chicago" musical and earlier play by Watkins); had his wife cheat on him, murder her lover, take ALL his money paying for her legal defense, bankrupt him, and then a day after her acquittal, publicly dump him and divorce him.
Wikipedia covers the life of the murderess after divorce. I find it rather annoying that the evil psycho has all details known, but her victimized husband didn't. So I tried to find out what happened to him. And failed. "Albert Annan biography" Google search lists zero results (same with "obituary" search), and he has no Wiki entry of his own.
So what happened to Albert Annan?

You can track this individual at the Family Search genealogical site.

Sometimes not being famous means you're doing better.

@MSW - do I REALLY need to add a citation to an obvious Wikipedia page? Edited but seems like it's not much of a value add

@DVK It save other readers the time to search for it themselfs.
